# GIMP Package dependencies cannot be resolved

Tags: dependencies, gimp

I need a little help from some friends. I installed GIMP-2.7 via PPA when I already had GIMP-2.6 installed via software center, and then I wanted to use 2.6 again. I am using Ubuntu 11.04. I removed the PPA for 2.7 let software centre update, closed and even logged out and then back in. But 2.7 was still there. So I figured I would remove it all and just re-install. I did: sudo apt-get remove --purge GIMP
And then tried installing GIMP via software centre but only to have this error:
[image: Screen shot of failed GIMP install]

I looked in my home directory and .GIMP-2.6 & .GIMP-2.7 are still there.
I thought remove & purge namely purge would completely remove them from my computer. How can i resolve the package dependencies and have GIMP-2.6 installed again.

Thank you very much for your time and answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `sudo apt-get autoremove` into the terminal(if u deleted correctly the PPA, this one should work).
Then make a `sudo apt-get update`
and then `sudo apt-get install gimp -y`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much. even the .GIMP-2.7 file was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Also, the files in your home folder won't dissapear, since those are not the installation files, but the configuration files. You can remove'm all like this:

```
rm -rvf $HOME/.gimp*
```

And about the installation, try the autoremove command of the previous answer.