# How to re-install GIMP 2.6 after trying GIMP 2.8?

Tags: dependencies, gimp, downgrade

Ok...
I tried GIMP 2.8, but felt more comfortable with 2.6. I removed the PPA's from Ubuntu Software Centre, removed and purged GIMP, and even rm the .gimp-2.8 folder. But when I go to install GIMP via terminal or the Software Centre I encounter this problem.

I know I should have known better, I had a VERY similar problem with [2.7](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60448/gimp-package-dependencies-cannot-be-resolved).
I tried those suggestions that worked for me last time, but I cannot get 2.6 back, see below for my error.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit.

Thank you for your time and answers.

[image: GIMP dependencies error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I just tried this on 12.04 64-bit, had the same problem, here's how I fixed it:

- Open a terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+T`
- Type these, one after the other:

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get remove gimp.* -y
  sudo apt-get autoremove -y
  sudo apt-get install gimp=2.6.12-1ubuntu1
  ```
- If it gives you dependency errors at any point and asks you to run `sudo apt-get -f install`, do so and then resume from that point.

Comment: Does anyone know if this answer will work on 12.10? And xubuntu, rather than ubuntu? I can't find the "otto-kesselgulasch" repository in /etc/apt/sources.list, so I wonder whether it's necessary anymore?

Comment: For anyone looking for a 12.10 "revert to gimp 2.6" solution, I found this one worked: http://askubuntu.com/a/243873/121193

Answer (score 3):

You can use YPPA Manager to purge the PPA.

This then should revert you back to the standard libraries. 
From there you can reinstall GIMP 2.6

ref:
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ppa-manage-gui-managing-ubuntu-ppas-linux/