# How do I add DBP to GIMP?

Tags: kubuntu, gimp, image-processing

I have Kubuntu 12.04.01 with GIMP 2.06. On a previous installation I used 
[DBP](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~hodsond/dbp.html) . I found it worked well on resizing images, and want to re-install it. Although I managed before, I cannot now remember how, though there must have been an easy way to do it! Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[**This answer**](http://blog.daveduncan.ca/?p=1256) was updated by author in early 2012 ...

Perhaps for you will be actual more to use new versions instead **dbp-1.1.5**.

> *Guide by Dave Duncan.*
>
> Download the **tgz** file to your desktop from [DBP archive](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~hodsond/dbp.html)
>
> Open a `terminal`, and run the following:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev gcc cpp g++
> ```
>
> You may be prompted for a **Yes/No** answer here (confirming the use of
>   hard drive space).  Just type ‘**y**’ and hit enter. Then, enter the
>   following:
>
> ```
> cd /usr/src/
> ```
>
> In the next command, substitute “[username]” with your username.
>   Then continue, entering the following commands in turn each time you
>   get a fresh command prompt.
>
> ```
> sudo tar -xvzf /home/[username]/Desktop/dbpSrc-1-1-5.tgz
> cd dbp-1.1.5
> ```
>
> Then build, and install package:
>
> ```
> sudo make
> make install
> ```
>
> Once all that is done, open up **GIMP** and go to (UPDATE Jan.2012):
>   **Filters >> Batch Process**
>   From the dropdown, select **Batch Process** and the world is your oyster!
>   Let me know if this works well for you.
>
> [Dave Duncan](http://blog.daveduncan.ca/?p=1256)

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks Dave, this went fine until the third line of code, once I realised I'd downloaded version1-1-9 rather than 1-1-5. Then the following:

Comment: Thanks Dave, this went fine until the third line of code, once I realised I'd downloaded version1-1-9 rather than 1-1-5. Then I got an error message: '    myuname@myuname-P5K:/usr/src$ cd dbp-1.1.9
myuname@myuname-P5K:/usr/src/dbp-1.1.9$ make
g++ -o dbp -Wall -O2 -I. *.cc -pthread ....... -lglib-2.0   -DGTK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED  
make install/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file dbp: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [dbp] Error 1    '
    I have omitted much as there is a limit on the characters allowed in a comment. Should I try to revert to 1-1-5 if I can find it?

Comment: try to use `sudo make` instead `make` ... and `make install` without changes as regular user ... and I am not Dave :)

Comment: Thanks, swift; cd dbp-1.1.5 is accepted, but '     sudo make' gives same error, a small part of which runs '    GTK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED    dbp.cc: In function ‘void query()’: …..
: error: ‘GtkSignalFunc’ was not declared in this scope...
gui.cc:71:17: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘fn’...
gui.cc:849:57: error: ‘GTK_FILE_SELECTION’ was not declared in this scope... '   There is not the space in this comment to reproduce the whole error message.

Comment: please post your error listing into [ubuntu pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post link ... perhaps you need to update your GIMP to version 2.6 (and use dbp-1.1.9) and also important your compiler configuration/libraries also should be updated. Cite: "You will need g++ and the gimp development packages for the appropriate Gimp version - if you can compile C++ and can build any other Gimp plugin, you should have no problems. The Makefiles are very primitive and can be edited directly if needed." It means solution exist, just some going wrong.

Comment: Thus if `sudo make` have errors means no point to run `make install` yet

Comment: refer [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/137689/38988) to update your GIMP to 2.6 ... dbp-1.1.9 and GIMP2.6 works good on 12.04 ... don't forget to update your gimp development packages before compilation.

Comment: and refer [**this guide**](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/04/13/building-gcc-4-7-on-ubuntu-12-04/) to update and configure your compiler environment...

Comment: THanks,again. I found the pastebin difficult, but believe I succeeded in posting the error ext with pastebin ref# 1404227.

Comment: I have not Upgraded to GIMP 2.8 - still on 2.6.12. Do I therefore need to **update** as suggested in your last two messages? If so do I need all of [this guide](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2012/04/13/building-gcc-4-7-on-ubuntu-12-04/) ? - it looks really long!

Comment: ok ... just need to say even though "this guide" is very complex way - it proposes most reliable method to maintain compiler workflow for Precise Pangolin ... however, sure, you can try any other official guide, like this: [Compiling Easy How To](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) or this: [Compiling Software](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware) ... all these guides looks long :)

Comment: These instructions worked perfectly for me on Kubuntu 13.04 (Raring), Gimp 2.8, and dbp 1.1.9 out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

At last I now have DBP  in my GIMP in which I acknowledge help from [swift](https://askubuntu.com/users/38988/swift) (above) [the community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingEasyHowTo) and [the author's blog](http://blog.daveduncan.ca/?p=1256), which I advise anyone wanting DBP to read.

Whilst I was trying to install, I looked for DBP under the *Script Fu* tab. It is now under *Filters*, so I don't know how many of the steps below were actually necessary; anyway here's what I did:

Download the tgz file to your desktop from [DBP archive](http://members.ozemail.com.au/~hodsond/dbp.html)
I downloaded **http://www.ozemail.com.au/~hodsond/dbpSrc-1-1-9.tgz**
There may be a later one, which would amend the following slightly.

Open a terminal, and run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt-get install libgimp2.0-dev gcc cpp g++
cd /usr/src/sudo tar -xvzf /home/MyUserName/Desktop/dbpSrc-1-1-9.tgz
cd dbp-1.1.9
```

Then I went to File manager (Dolphin), navigated to *root/usr/src/dbp1.1.9*. Firstly I right clicked on every file then selected *Properties>Permissions* to ensure that MyUserName was owner then checked the *“is executable”* box. I then opened the file `Makefile` with  *GNU Emacs*  and amended the sixth line to read 
 `#NODEPS = -DGTK_DISABLE_DEPRECATED`.

Then back to the terminal...

```
sudo make
make install
```

I hope that this will help other inexperienced users who want to install this excellent plug-in.