# How can I go back to GIMP 2.6?

Tags: package-management, gimp

On an old PC, I have Lubuntu 12.10. during GIMP installation, the newest version was installed (ver. 2.8), but I think its a little heavy for an old machine like mine with a poor Intel Celeron CPU (Ram 1GB, VGA 128)

How can I go back to GIMP 2.6?

Comment: If you're handy with the wine emulator you should be able to install any version of gimp going back to the beginning of time.  https://superuser.com/questions/748488/linux-install-old-version-of-gimp

Answer (score 7):

Try doing the forward port approach (works for more packages than just Gimp):

1. Add the `precise` main repositories to your system.

   Create a file like `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/precise-for-gimp.list` containing

   ```
   deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
   deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
   deb http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
   deb-src http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
   deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
   ```

   Replace the mirror (here `nl.archive.ubuntu.com`) with the one you would like to use.
2. Add a file with the appropriate pinning to allow downgrading of a certain set of packages, in e.g. `/etc/apt/preferences.d/10-pin-gimp-to-precise`:

   ```
   Package: *gimp*
   Pin: release a=precise-security
   Pin-Priority: 1001

   Package: *gimp*
   Pin: release a=precise-updates
   Pin-Priority: 1001
   ```
3. Run `sudo apt-get update`
4. Run `sudo apt-get -s install gimp` (`-s` to simulate only)
5. Check whether the output makes sense. If not, and it can't manage to satisfy the dependencies, then consider reverting the actions above. If it does work, then actually run the actions to be performed by re-running the previous command without the `-s` option.

This approach will provide you best flexibility and security-update support, as it's just using the repositories rather than a specific version. It may be a PITA to set up, though.

Comment: While it installs and runs the splash screen, it segfaults and even crashes Unity in 12.10...

Comment: Worked perfectly for me (xubuntu 12.10). Thanks gertvdijk!

Comment: @gertvdijk Could you please explain what this does? As I understand, this is the procedure you could use in general, if you want to use older versions of the programs on your system? If I should use Ubuntu 13.10, I understand I use `saucy` instead of `precise`

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov This approach could indeed be considered general. It's forward porting an older application onto a newer Ubuntu distribution. `precise` is the source distribution in this example, so if you're running `saucy`, but you like a package version from `quantal`, use `quantal` here. Note it won't work always due to dependencies.

Comment: @gertvdijk Thanks! Ok, I see that `precise` is indeed the latest I can use if I want 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply download gimp 2.6 from ftp://ftp.gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.6/ and run

```
  tar xvfz gimp-2.6.x.tar.gz   # unpack the sources
  cd gimp-2.6.x                # change to the toplevel directory
  ./configure                  # run the `configure' script
  make                         # build GIMP
  make install                 # install GIMP
```

You can change the v2.6 in the url to change the version.

To first uninstall gimp:

```
sudo apt-get remove gimp
```

Comment: Yup, this is one way. But the general issue with compile from source is that it fiddles with your current dpkg-managed system files (so some may be overwritten later on updates) and it's hard to undo the steps taken in case the `make install` actions did something you didn't quite like.

Comment: you know gertvdijk, your way is pretty hard for me. im just a newcomer in linux. this solution is much simpler, but you said it gonna cause troubles. im really confused, so what should i do. isnt there a simple way without trouble?

Comment: @Merii All will be pretty hard. Have you tried this approach in this answer? The `./configure` step here will not run until you forward ported libgegl as well, for example. It's not an easy task to change versions of applications due to the high level of integration. This is intentional and how Ubuntu works. Consider sticking to 12.04 on an older PC.

Answer (score -2):

Try this (it worked for me):

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

Comment: Downvote because the original question indirectly states that GIMP was updated. There's no reason to believe that the user is using a PPA version of GIMP. As such, the suggested answer is not relevant.