# How to get Gimp 2.6.6 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gimp

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I need Gimp 2.6.6 for a class.  I tried to get it by typing `sudo apt-get install gimp=2.6.6-1ubuntu1`
However, it said `E: Version '2.6.6-1ubuntu1' for 'gimp' was not found`
Any ideas?

Comment: This has the instructions http://askubuntu.com/questions/243865/how-to-go-back-to-gimp-2-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having trouble with the tarball so I got the Windows version from oldapps.com and ran it using Wine.

Answer (score 0):

you can download it from this mirror  and install it `ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/ftp.gimp.org/pub/gimp/v2.6/`