# How to go back to Gimp2.6 (2018)

Tags: software-installation, gimp

With older versions of ubuntu [this questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243865/how-to-go-back-to-gimp-2-6) answers still worked. Now they don't.

The repositories aren't reachable and building from source fails because of dependency errors.

I've found [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~malcscott/+archive/ubuntu/gimp-2.6), but it isn't working either:

> The following packages have unmet dependencies:
>    libgegl-0.0-0 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

How do you go back to the last sane version of gimp: 2.6?

Comment: One easy way is to install an appropriate flavor of 14.04 or Ubuntu 16.04. Other ways depend upon your skill and your hardware's capabilities.

Comment: Why "sane"? If your problem is the Save-v.s.-Export controversy in 2.8, there are ways around it. They should also work in 2.10 (which is really a quantum leap from 2.8).

Comment: Any software that answers me "no" upon telling it to save is clearly insane. I tried the workarounds. They didn't work out for me. 2.6 works for me and the only way it could be better is by allowing a shortcut to automatically get a rectangle selection with certain size, like 300px*250px, since it's a little tough to select that with a mouse unless the zoom is right.

Comment: You can save that as a preset for the Rectangle select tool, or even set the Rectangle tool to that and then save the tools options in the Preferences to make that the default.

Comment: That's neat, but without the ability to toggle between fixed and free via keyboard it's not all that useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Malcolm Scott's repository using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:malcscott/gimp-2.6
```

gimp depends on libpng12-0 which is not available in official repository of Bionic. You can download it from [Xenial packages download page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libpng12-0/download) or [direct download](http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb). Install it using;

```
sudo dpkg -i libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

Now install gimp using

```
sudo apt install gimp
```