# How to go back to Gimp2.6 (2022)

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, gimp, downgrade

The method from [four years ago](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103854/how-to-go-back-to-gimp2-6-2018) no longer works:

```
$ sudo aptitude install gimp
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gimp{b} gimp-data{a} libbabl-0.0-0{a} libgegl-0.0-0{ab} libgimp2.0{a} liblcms1{a} libmng2{a} 
  libopenexr6{ab} libtiff4{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
Need to get 11,0 MB of archives. After unpacking 56,2 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgegl-0.0-0 : Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

 gimp : Depends: python-gtk2 (>= 2.8.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

        Depends: libpng12-0 (>= 1.2.13-4) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

        Depends: libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 (>= 1.3.10) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

 libopenexr6 : Depends: libilmbase12 (>= 2.2.0) which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     gimp [Not Installed]                               
2)     libgegl-0.0-0 [Not Installed]                      
3)     libopenexr6 [Not Installed]                        

     Leave the following dependencies unresolved:         
4)     gimp-data recommends gimp
```

So how do you install Gimp2.6 now?

```
$ cat /etc/upstream-release/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Focal Fossa"
```

Comment: Gimp 2.6 is no longer in the Ubuntu repositories. Nor Debian archives. If you want that specific old version, you must compile it from source yourself now.

Comment: This may be another [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you want to use Gimp 2.6?

Comment: Gimp introduced a bunch of additional hoops to jump through when you open a jpg and save it as a jpg. It then also bothers you about an unsaved xcf, despite just having saved my jpg. This workflow is a lot smoother in gimp2.6. (If I get a xcf file at the end I made a mistake.) I need Gimp for pixel accurate selection, which isn't available in other tools I tried out. Like selecting exactly a rectangle of 300x300 pixel. Or resizing an image to 200px width and arbitrary height and then selecting a pixel perfect height of 200px to end up with a 200x200 pixel image.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi https://askubuntu.com/questions/1103854/how-to-go-back-to-gimp2-6-2018 (Also fixed in the post)

Comment: Workaround for saving as jpg by default - You will have to export the image instead of saving (but you can map the shortcut `ctrl + s` to export - here's how https://itsfoss.com/how-to-solve-gimp-2-8-does-not-save-in-jpeg-or-png-format/ ), and you can make jpg the default export format (here's how https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/98999/113198). Note that you probably cannot install such an old version of Gimp in recent versions of Ubuntu, due to dependency issues.

Comment: I know this workaround, but then gimp still bothers you about unsaved xcf files, so it's not viable. Just too many things you have to click through, which gets irritating after you do a bunch of pictures.

Comment: @Ocean There are scripts for 2.8/2.10 to go around this. You can also train your fingers to do Ctr-D. However as a person who answers questions about Gimp I no longer see people asking to un-flatten an image because they "saved" to JPG and then forgot to save to XCF.

Comment: @xenoid Where can I find these scripts and how do I install them? I'd never want to "un-flatten" anything. Once I save, I am done with the image forever. If I want something else, I start from the source again.

Comment: @Ocean https://shallowsky.com/software/gimp-save/